# no arg method compiler error not generated

Tags: java, oop, overloading

Here is my code:

```
public class XYZ {

    public static void overLoaded(Object a) {
        System.out.println("IN OBJECT");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        overLoaded();
    }
}
```

I expected compile time error as there is no arg method but instead the output is coming out to be **IN OBJECT**.

Please explain the output.

Comment: Your code won't compile.  If you think it compiles you did something wrong.

Comment: http://ideone.com/o7sugO prints an error message `Main.java:16: error: method overLoaded in class Ideone cannot be applied to given types;
overLoaded();`

Comment: Let me guess, you have changed the class to the code you have posted but are running the old version?

Answer (score 5):

I just tried your code and am getting:

```
method  overLoaded in class XYZ cannot be applied to given types;
overLoaded();
^
  required: Object
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

1 error
```

So, if you *are* getting the behaviour you describe, either your compiler is seriously broken or the code you've given us is not the code you have.